# Convert Access 2000 application to access 2013 application

Tags: vba, ms-access, migration, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2000

We have an Access 2000 application linked to SQL Server 2008 database. Now we are going to convert it to Access 2013 application (again linked to SQL Server 2008). What issues I'm going to face, and what is the best solution to take? Thanks for your advices.

Comment: How does your application access SQL Server? Does it use ADO or ODBC Linked tables? Is it an "Access Data Project"?

Comment: Hi HK1, It uses ADO Linked tables and Yes it is Access Data Project (.adp files)

Comment: Access 2013 doesn't support Access Data Projects. Are you sure you're using ADO linked tables? I don't think there is any such thing. ADO is code only and Linked Tables are usually (always?) ODBC.

Comment: FYI, we had an Access 2000 application with ODBC tables linked to SQL Server, but we also had lots of ADO code. The ADO was for a variety of uses: local queries against linked tables, queries resident on SQL Server, etc. BUT: we didn't use ADP...